# Question about a function being continuous

Tags: analysis

Let $\{r_1,r_2,...\}$ be the set of rational numbers in $[0,1]$ and

$g_n(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x-r_n|}} & x\neq r_n; \\ 3 & x=r_n.\end{cases}$

This is continuous by definition ?
for all $ϵ>0$, there exists $δ>0$ such that for all $y$, if $|x−y|<δ$, then $|f(x)−f(y)|<ϵ$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$g_n$ is not continuous at $r_n$: if $(x_k)$ is a sequence in $[0,1] \setminus \{r_n\}$ with $x_k \to r_n$ as $k \to \infty$, then $g_n(x_k) \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty.$

Answer (score 0):

It's discontinuous, for $x$ close to $r_n$ values of $\frac1{\sqrt{|x-r_n|}}$ get arbitrarily large, so for small $\varepsilon$ you won't find such $\delta$.